# package.json does not update dependencies

Tags: json, npm, angular-cli

I recently tried to run my friend's project on my machine using the `angular-cli`. The dependencies in the `package.json` were old on his machine so I tried to update them using the following commands:

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

The commang `ng serve` did render a few modules but I get these errors.

[image: errors]

What should I do?

Comment: Did you install `@angular/animations`?

Answer (score 0):

Install and save the angular animations to the package.json file.

```
npm install @angular/animations@latest --save
```

Comment: Yeah now I have another error : ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/pink-bluegrey.css' in '/Users/sarthaksachdeva/Desktop/Source Files/Ang/code/store-front/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./src/styles.css 3:10-207
 @ ./src/styles.css
 @ multi ./src/styles.css